# argparse with "+" option

Tags: python, argparse

I have been using `argparse` to parse command line options and worked great. Now I would like to use `+` instead of `-` for some options.

Ex: `script.py +opt -f <filename>`

Is it possible to use such `+` options with `argparse`?

Comment: Yes, simply set the [`prefix_chars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars) option.

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick replies and sorry for asking something that I should have found in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You can set the [`prefix_chars` option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#prefix-chars) to something other than `'-'`:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars='-+')
```

at which point you can start using either `-` or `+` in the definition of arguments:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars='-+')
>>> parser.add_argument('+opt', action='store_true')
_StoreTrueAction(option_strings=['+opt'], dest='opt', nargs=0, const=True, default=False, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.add_argument('-f')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-f'], dest='f', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)
>>> parser.parse_args(['+opt', '-f', '<filename>'])
Namespace(f='<filename>', opt=True)
```

The above defines `+opt`; you have to use the right prefix to invoke it, `-opt` won't work.